# Is it possible to use IBM JVM to execute the SonarQube Scanner (aka sonar-runner)?

Tags: java, mysql, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am confused about the java version, I am trying to run the sonar-runner-2.4 in s390x Suse, I only have IBM JRE 1.8, but I met some issues, so my question is: does IBM JRE/JDK 1.8 is supported by sonar-runner-2.4?
btw, my SonarQube server & MySQL are running in another windows 7 machine.

Please let me know, thank you in advance!

Comment: SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0 IBM Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 3.0.101-0.7.17-default s390x
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: SonarQube Server 6.0
21:29:37.473 DEBUG - Publish global mode
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
Total time: 1.340s
Final Memory: 3M/6M
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller

Comment: You should edit that information into the question instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO, the IBM JVM is not supported, see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements.